# Any existing Dictionary<T, List<T>> in which the value collection cannot contain the key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need the following (using string as the type here for brevity):

```
MyDictionary : IDictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _collection;
    ...
    // The collection cannot contain the key
    public void Add(string key, List<string> value)
    {
        _collection.Add(key, new List<string>(value.RemoveAll(p => p == key));
    }
}
```

So in use you might have:

```
string myName = "Superstringcheese";
List<string> myFriends = new List<string> {"John", "Jane", "Jerry"};

string yourName = "Someone";
List<string> yourFriends = new List<string> {"John", "Bill", "Ted"};

var myDic = new MyDictionary();

// It's okay that each of us (each key) has some friends that are the same. It's not okay for me to have myself as a friend. The add method would check if the key is contained by the value collection and remove it if necessary.
myDic.Add(myName, myFriends);
myDic.Add(yourName, yourFriends);
```

Before I go reinventing any wheels, is there a native collection type that does this, or does anyone know of a popular implementation?

Comment: So you are trying to define a dictionary with multiple values to one key? I tried to do that once, using a struct. I'm confused on why the key would be in the value list? Can you show us an example of using the Add method.

Comment: Sure, I added an example of usage.

Comment: @Superstringcheese: From your example, I'd say the structure of your data is a "Dictionary of Lists". The fact that the key can't be in the list is more of a 'business rule' or 'domain rule'. The distinction between data structure and rule is vague sometimes, admittedly. But anyway I think what you're describing is quite specific so I'd be surprised if there's any prior implementation worth reusing.

Comment: I suspect you're right about this, a clue being that I'm having a tough time thinking up a name for its generalized form. I'll leave it open a bit and see if anyone has any insight, gotchas, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can help with this bit:

> Is there a native collection type that does this?

No.